# Tabularx neverending rows

Tags: tables, tabularx

So basically my tables work fine under the tabular format, but in some cases I need to use tabularx because they are too large to fit within the normal textwidth.

However, the rows become infinitely long, due to an erroneous extra column it seems?

EDIT: Changed the table to my actual table. Image1 shows the same code using tabular and without the \noindent\makebox. As you can see, the table is too wide and floats slightly off to the right, hence I try using tabularx to make it wider, such that it can be centred on the page. However it gives a weird unending rows.

Image:
[image]

[image]

In image1, the table is wider than the text width, though at least it correctly ends. Hence I try using tabularx in the code below, which results in image2:

Code:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\label{table-A_3_posthoc}
\centering
\small
\caption[One-way ANOVA tests for scenarios 14, 16, 18 and 19-22]{One-way ANOVA tests showing the variation between sample means in three different internetwork topologies. Comparisons without a significant level (SL) were deemed statistically insignificantly different i.e. $p > 0.05$.\\}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{tabularx}{1.5\textwidth}{l|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r}
\toprule
One-way ANOVA & SL($\langle k \rangle$) & SL($\overline{C_E}$) & SL($D$) & SL($\ell$) & SL($G_E$) & SL($C_G$) & SL($\Phi$) & SL($\Gamma$)\\
\midrule
14 and 19 & 0.010 & & 0.010 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001\\
16 and 20 & 0.001 & & 0.010 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.050 & & \\
18 and 21 & 0.001 & 0.050 & 0.050 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.010 & 0.010\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}}
\end{table}
```

Preamble:

```
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[margin=1.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} % For using * for no eq. numbers
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[]{graphicx} % For inserting figures etc
\usepackage{booktabs} % For \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
```

Comment: In the example above, you explicitely ask the table to be extra-large (width = `1.5\textwidth`). You ask for a table one and a half times as wide as the text. Is it really what you want?

Comment: Welcome  to TeX SX! I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to obtain with this code. A table wider than `\textwidth` that be centred?

Comment: A minimal working example would be a great idea.

Comment: `l` and `r` columns are always single line. You do not want `tabularx` just change the column type from `l` to (say) `p{3cm}`

Comment: in your answer/comment you give no indication of why you need tabularx or makebox here. standard tabular will allow line breaking in cells if you specify a column type that allows linebreaking.

Comment: @Christoph Frings In my actual tables they span wider than the text width, which is why I need tabularx. In the tiny example I showed clearly it doesn't need the extra width, but I am trying to highlight the error with the extra empty column.

Comment: if you specified the tabularx to be \textwidth not 1.5\textwidth it would still over-shoot the right margin as you are forcing a space on the left due to the missing `%` after `\makebox[\textwidth]{` (although it would be better to delete that command rather than add the `%`)

Comment: Should the two columns be equally wide? If not, which column should be wider?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have changed the code to include the % and the error remains the same. Updated OP for more detail.

Comment: well of course if you specify it is 1.5 times the width of the page it is still too wide, as i say the extra space would be noticable if the table was \textwidth wide, but tabularx is no help at all for a table as you have provided, it is all about _linebreaking_ and  you do not want linebreaking in a numeric table.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle To clarify. the reason for desiring it to be wider is so that it can still be centred on the page, such that it slightly spills to the 0.25 to left and right, rather than it currently spilling 0.2 to the right or however much. I'm not sure what you mean about linebreaking, how else am I supposed to specify a now row to be entered?

Comment: tabularx adjusts the table width by changing the widths for _linebreaking_ within table cells, it is designed (by me:-) for textual tables. It can do nothing useful for tables of data where you do not want linebreaking within the cells (other than perhaps table headings).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, that clears some things up, thankyou. Normally I would properly read documentation before jumping in and asking questions but it is a few days until my dissertation is due and I left it very last minute... I am using the answer posted below but thanks for the continued help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the `tabularx` environment, do make sure to feature at least one column that employs the `X` column type. In the example code below, I suggest assigning a centered version of the `X` column type to the 8 data columns.

There is no need for the `\makebox` "wrapper". Given the width of the textblock, there's no need for the `\small` font size directive either. Since the width of the `tabularx` environment is (or at least should be!) `\textwidth`, the `\centering` instruction is redundant. And, do get rid of the unneeded vertical bars.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
% Define a centered version of the "X" column type:
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[margin=1.4in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\label{table-A_3_posthoc}
\caption[One-way ANOVA tests for scenarios 14, 16, 18 and 19-22]{One-way 
  ANOVA tests showing the variation between sample means in three 
  different internetwork topologies. Comparisons without a significant 
  level (SL) were deemed statistically insignificantly different, i.e., 
  $p > 0.05$.}

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{@{} l *{8}{C} @{}}
\toprule
One-way ANOVA & SL($\langle k \rangle$) & SL($\overline{C_E}$) & SL($D$) 
  & SL($\ell$) & SL($G_E$) & SL($C_G$) & SL($\Phi$) & SL($\Gamma$)\\
\midrule
14 and 19 & 0.010 &       & 0.010 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001\\
16 and 20 & 0.001 &       & 0.010 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.050 & & \\
18 and 21 & 0.001 & 0.050 & 0.050 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.010 & 0.010\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}



\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
% define a centered version of the "X" column type:
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[margin=1.4in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\label{table-A_3_posthoc}
\centering
\caption[One-way ANOVA tests for scenarios 14, 16, 18 and 19-22]{One-way ANOVA tests showing the variation between sample means in three different internetwork topologies. Comparisons without a significant level (SL) were deemed statistically insignificantly different, i.e., $p > 0.05$.}

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{@{} l *{7}{C} c @{}}
\toprule
One-way ANOVA & SL($\langle k \rangle$) & SL($\overline{C_E}$) & SL($D$) & SL($\ell$) & SL($G_E$) & SL($C_G$) & SL($\Phi$) & SL($\Gamma$)\\
\midrule
14 and 19 & 0.010 & & 0.010 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001\\
16 and 20 & 0.001 & & 0.010 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.050 & & \\
18 and 21 & 0.001 & 0.050 & 0.050 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.010 & 0.010\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution too. It seemed my main problem was not using at least one column with the x type. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\newcommand\hd[1]{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]%[!h]

\centering
\small
\caption[One-way ANOVA tests for scenarios 14, 16, 18 and 19-22]{One-way ANOVA tests showing the variation between sample means in three different internetwork topologies. Comparisons without a significant level (SL) were deemed statistically insignificantly different i.e. $p > 0.05$.%
%\\ never end a paragraph with \\
\label{table-A_3_posthoc}% never use \label before caption
}


\begin{tabular}{l|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r}
\toprule
\hd{One-way\\ANOVA}&
\hd{SL\\($\langle k \rangle$)} &
\hd{SL\\($\overline{C_E}$)}&
\hd{SL\\($D$)}&
\hd{SL\\($\ell$)}&
\hd{SL\\($G_E$)}&
\hd{SL\\($C_G$)}&
\hd{SL\\($\Phi$)}&
\hd{SL\\($\Gamma$)}\\
\midrule
14 and 19 & 0.010 & & 0.010 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001\\
16 and 20 & 0.001 & & 0.010 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.050 & & \\
18 and 21 & 0.001 & 0.050 & 0.050 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.010 & 0.010\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh I didn't realise it was you that also answered it, hah. Well thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

Table environment `tabularx`is not intended to set table wider than text width! With proper use of column type -- it should be based on `X` column type --  it determine column with itself and longer text in cells break into more lines. So never use only tabular column types (`l`, `c`, `r`, `p{...}`) in `tabularx` as you do.

If you like to some place have table wider than is text width (but not wider than page width as it is in your case):

[image]

than you need to appropriate change text width locally for table. This can be done on different ways, one of among them (beside of one you used) is for example use of the package `changepage`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.4in,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
    \hline
Hello & Right\\
    \hline
Yes & No\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
meanwhile the question is changed and from it now follows, that the table actually perfectly fit in `\textwidth` ... If you for some reason still like stick with `tabularx`, you can rewrite your table as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.4in,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\label{table-A_3_posthoc}
\small
\caption[One-way ANOVA tests for scenarios 14, 16, 18 and 19-22]{One-way ANOVA tests showing the variation between sample means in three different internetwork topologies. Comparisons without a significant level (SL) were deemed statistically insignificantly different i.e. $p > 0.05$.\\}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|
                             *{8}{S[table-format=1.3]}
                             }%r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r}
\toprule
One-way ANOVA & {SL($\langle k \rangle$)} & {SL($\overline{C_E}$)} & {SL($D$)} & {SL($\ell$)} & {SL($G_E$)} & {SL($C_G$)} & {SL($\Phi$)} & {SL($\Gamma$)}\\
\midrule
14 and 19 & 0.010 & & 0.010 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001\\
16 and 20 & 0.001 & & 0.010 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.050 & & \\
18 and 21 & 0.001 & 0.050 & 0.050 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.010 & 0.010\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the makebox way used by the OP is also OK if you really need an over-sized table, but the question has been altered with a different table example that shows it's not really over-sized and doesn't need tabularx:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, in the my first look i overlooked this, but personally I more prefer to use `changepage`. It better control the table protrusion out of text if it is desired to be asymmetric (for example only on outer text border). Well, meanwhile after OP edits of question the situation is very different! Table actually perfectly fit into text width ...